# Need to get the day before date from the Input xml

Tags: xml, date, xslt-2.0

Need to get the day before date for certain attribute value and replace with mentioned date from the input xml

Input XML I'm having, the `<Date>` need to change the before day when `Cost:Date:date4`

```
<section>
<Plans>
<Date>5/1/2021</Date>
</Plans>
    
<p>date: <keyword keyref="Cost:Date:date4"/></p>
</section>
```

XSL I have tried for the above xml:

```
<xsl:template match="keyword[contains(@keyref, 'Cost:Date:date4')]">
        <xsl:param name="section" as="element()" tunnel="yes">
            <empty/>
        </xsl:param>
        <keyword keyref="Cost:Date:date4">
            <xsl:call-template name="format_variable">
                <xsl:with-param name="cur_keyref" select="@keyref"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="cur_value"
                    select="$section//Plans/Date"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="cur_format" select="'date4'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </keyword>
    </xsl:template>
    
          <xsl:template name="format_variable">
        <xsl:param name="cur_keyref" as="xs:string">MISSING</xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="cur_value" as="xs:string">MISSING</xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="cur_format" as="xs:string">MISSING</xsl:param>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$cur_format = 'date4'">
                <xsl:variable name="date_pieces" select="tokenize($cur_value, '/')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="month" select="$date_pieces[1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="day" select="$date_pieces[2]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="year" select="$date_pieces[3]"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '1'">
                        <xsl:text>January</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '2'">
                        <xsl:text>February</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '3'">
                        <xsl:text>March</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '4'">
                        <xsl:text>April</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '5'">
                        <xsl:text>May</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '6'">
                        <xsl:text>June</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '7'">
                        <xsl:text>July</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '8'">
                        <xsl:text>August</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '9'">
                        <xsl:text>September</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '10'">
                        <xsl:text>October</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '11'">
                        <xsl:text>November</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$month = '12'">
                        <xsl:text>December</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                
                <xsl:variable name="day_before" select="concat(' ', $day, ', ', $year)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="xs:dayTimeDuration($day_before) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
```

Before that I have used `<xsl:value-of select="$day_before - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>`, but I'm getting the arthmetic error for xslt 2.0

Expected Output would be:

```
Date: April 31, 2021
```

But when I'm running I'm getting the error `Invalid duration value ' 1, 2021' (missing 'P')`. Please help me to resolve this issue. I'm using XLST 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your input format into an XSLT/XPath `xs:date` you can use string manipulations and number formatting, then you can substract an `xs:dayTimeDuration` and get the new `xs:date`:

```
let $components := tokenize('5/1/2021', '/')!xs:integer(.),
    $date := xs:date($components[3] || '-' || format-integer($components[1], '00') || '-' || format-integer($components[2], '00')),
    $oneDay := xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
return $date - $oneDay
```

That would give e.g. `2021-04-30`, to format it use `format-date` e.g. `format-date($date - $oneDay, '[MNn] [D01], [Y0000]')` which gives e.g. `April 30, 2021`.

As for the broader context, I think you want e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="keyword[contains(@keyref, 'Cost:Date:date4')]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:value-of
            select="let $components := tokenize(ancestor::section/Plans/Date, '/')!xs:integer(.),
    $date := xs:date($components[3] || '-' || format-integer($components[1], '00') || '-' || format-integer($components[2], '00')),
    $oneDay := xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
return format-date($date - $oneDay, '[MNn] [D01], [Y0000]')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: On which place I have to include your code?

Comment: @User501, see whether the edit helps. The only issue might be if you really use an XSLT 2 processor and not an XSLT 3 one then `let` might not be available, you would need to use XSLT variables e.g. `<xsl:variable name="components" select="for $token in tokenize(ancestor::section/Plans/Date, '/') return xs:integer($token)"/><xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(concat($components[3], '-' ,format-integer($components[1], '00'), '-', format-integer($components[2], '00')))"/>...`.

Comment: similiar kind of Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764338/need-to-get-the-last-year-from-the-input-xml, Please see

Comment: @User501, well, try to understand and apply what you accepted as answer here by substracting a year instead of a day.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I received it through this code `<xsl:value-of select="let $components := tokenize($cur_value, '/')!xs:integer(.),
                    $date := xs:date($components[3] || '-' || format-integer($components[1], '00') || '-' || format-integer($components[2], '00')),
                    $oneDay := xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y')
                return format-date($date - $oneDay, '[Y0000]')"/>` Thank You So much